# (Laravel) Запретить сброс данных после сбоя проверки

Tags: php, laravel, form

Я полный новичок в бэкенде и первым фреймворком я выбрал Laravel. Я по видеоуроку начал делать форму заполнения отзыва, параллельно при этом добавляя изменения, которых недостаёт (внешний вид или критерии для валидации, в основном). Самое главное, мне не нравится, что данные в текстовых полях всё время сбрасываются после валидации. Удовлетворяющую информацию я не смог найти, так как либо непонятно зачем, либо непонятно где.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как это сделать просто и грамотно? Если есть на уму какой-нибудь очень полезный источник, то это тоже может сильно помочь. Очень нужно также, чтобы вы указывали куда вписывать какие-либо строки кода, так как это также является одним из основных причин, почему я не могу это сделать по гайдам.

**Разметка:**

```
@extends('main')

@section('main_content')
<form class="ml-auto mr-auto p-3 px-md-4 mb-3 w-50" method="post" action="/review/check">
    @csrf
    <h1 class="mb-4">Отзыв</h1>
    @if($errors->any())
        <div class="alert alert-danger text-danger bg-dark border border-danger">
            <ul class="mb-0">
                @foreach($errors->all() as $error)
                    <li>{{ $error }}</li>
                @endforeach
            </ul>
        </div>
    @endif
    <input autocomplete="off" type="email" name="email" id="email" placeholder="Введите Email" class="form-control bg-dark text-light border border-secondary"><br>
    <input autocomplete="off" type="text" name="subject" id="subject" placeholder="Введите отзыв" class="form-control bg-dark text-light border border-secondary"><br>
    <textarea autocomplete="off" name="message" id="message" class="form-control bg-dark text-light border border-secondary" placeholder="Введите сообщение"></textarea><br>
    <button type="sumbit" class="btn btn-success w-100">Отправить</button>
</form>
@endsection
```

**Контроллер:**

```
public function review(){
    return view('review');
}

public function review_check(Request $request){
    $valid = $request->validate([
        'email' => 'required|min:4|max:60',
        'subject' => 'required|min:4|max:100',
        'message' => 'required|min:8|max:500'
    ]);
}
```

**Роут:**

```
Route::get('/review', 'App\Http\Controllers\Main@review');
Route::post('/review/check', 'App\Http\Controllers\Main@review_check');
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Воспользуйтесь методом [`old`](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/helpers#method-old).

***Пример:***

```
<input value="{{ old('email') }}"> type="email" name="email">
```

Раздел документации по заполнению старыми данными: [Retrieving Old Input](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/requests#retrieving-old-input).

Comment: Ух ты! Такое простое и рабочее решение. Ответ понятен, краток и имеет в себе дополнительный ресурс, а самое главное, что помогло мне. Огромнейшее вам спасибо! Отмечаю ответ как найлучший.

Comment: Хочу добавить только то, что изучение фреймоворков (да и не только их) следует начинать не с каких-то там уроков, а именно с чтения документации. Всё сразу конечно не запомните, но что-то останется в голове и уже будете знать где искать.

Comment: @AntonMironov, документация для моей башки является одним сплошным текстом, который трудно воспринять и на который нужно потратить уйму времени, гадая что мне понадобится, а что нет. Мне легче через видеоуроки, в которых все сразу важное показывается перед глазами. Через документацию изучаю исключительно библиотеки и препроцессоры.
Но я уже вижу, что ответ крылся всё это время в доке и мне стоит его чаще открывать, пытаться вникать, мотивируя себя тем, что я смогу в совершенстве (или хотя бы почти совершенно) пользоваться фреймом. Спасибо за совет! Обязательно буду начинать с доки!